# How to do a multi-level relationship query on Chatter/Comments

Tags: chatter, soql, apex

Trying to perform a SOQL query to retrieve related `FeedItems` **and** `FeedComments` (on the related FeedItems) to my sObject and I retrieved a warning that multi-level queries aren't allowed.

Can anyone think of an optimization that will reduce the risk of overflowing script statements and allow me to retrieve related `FeedItems` and the `FeedComments` related to those items

```
List<myObject> sObjectsWithComments = [SELECT Id (SELECT Id,Body,ParentId, (SELECT 
                                       Id, CommentBody, FeedItemId FROM FeedComments) FROM
                                       Feeds) FROM myObject];
```

If this isn't achievable it's still possible to manually selected the `FeedComment` and create a map, and do a manually association, but I really think this is something the database should be responsible for.

**Update**

I guess I should also mention some of the difficult requirements:

1. List item: In any given instance the page I'm working with may have
   over 100 object records
2. I need count the number of `FeedItems` and `FeedComments` that have been created by another user since a `LastVisit__c` field on the parent object. *Hence the issue with looping*

So I have a goal of something more akin too (psuedo-code):

```
List<myObject> sObjectsWithComments = [SELECT Id,LastVisit__c (SELECT Id,Body,ParentId, (SELECT 
       Id, CommentBody, FeedItemId, CreatedDate FROM FeedComments WHERE CreatedDate > Parent.LastVisit__c) FROM
       Feeds WHERE CreatedDate > Parent.LastVisit__c) FROM myObject];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Separate the feed from the object to avoid a nested query.

```
List<FeedItem> feedWithComments = [SELECT Id,Body,ParentId, (SELECT 
                                   Id, CommentBody, FeedItemId FROM FeedComments) FROM
                                   FeedItem WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM
                                   myObject WHERE Field = 'value')];
```

Comment: updated some of my requirements, I forgot to mention I'm already doing this, but I need to reduce the results based on a field in each of the _parent sobject_ so I have to loop and match each record with it's parent manually because I can't limit each set of related records by a parent objects field value.

Comment: You can do that by executing a correlated subquery in your where clause:
`List<FeedItem> feedWithComments = [SELECT Id,Body,ParentId, (SELECT 
                                   Id, CommentBody, FeedItemId FROM FeedComments) FROM
                                   FeedItem WHERE ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM <Object> WHERE <Field> = <value>)];`

Comment: @jordan.baucke Did the correlated subquery answer your question? Is this question still open?

Comment: I'll give it a shot...